# How to upload image or file through multipart form data with multi parameters in Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, multipartform-data, nsurlsession

I have a problem uploading a picture or file through image picker controller. I have selected image through image picker then pass the parameters event_id, booking_id, memeber_id, and upfile. All these values are in the form-data format in Postman. How to send these value to API? In postman, it's running perfectly but here in Xcode its showing error. I am thinking the parameters, I am sending in that error contains.

```
func UploadRequest() {
    let x: Int = defaults.integer(forKey: "ObjectID")
    user_id = String(x)
    auth_key = defaults.value(forKey: "AuthKey") as! String
    var request2 = URLRequest(url: uploadDoc! as URL)
    request2.httpMethod = "POST"

    //define the multipart request type
    if (self.img.image == nil) {
        return
    }
    let image_data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.img.image!, 1)
    if(image_data == nil) {
        return
    }
    let boundry = generateBoundaryString()
    request2.setValue(user_id, forHTTPHeaderField: "user_id")
    request2.setValue(auth_key, forHTTPHeaderField: "auth_key")
    request2.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundry)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let param = ["event_id":evId,"booking_id":receivedId,"member_id":memId]
    print(param)
    request2.httpBody = createBody(params: param, filePathKey: "upfile", imageDatakey: image_data! as NSData, boundary: boundry) as Data
    self.jsonDifferentRunDoc(passString: request2)
}

//Generate Boundry String
func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
    return "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
}

func createBody(params: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String, imageDatakey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
    let body = NSMutableData()
    if params != nil {
        for (key, value) in params! {
            body.appendString(boundary)
            body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }

    let filename = "jk.jpg"
    let mimetype = "image/jpg"

    body.appendString(boundary)
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upfile\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    body.append(imageDatakey as Data)
    body.appendString("\r\n")
    body.appendString("--".appending(boundary.appending("--")))

    //print("Body = \(body)")
    return body
}
```

It is showing error when I run this function.

Comment: What error showing?

Comment: Tell me error please

Comment: Its showing error in API. Framework error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is syntax error while uploading boundary:

```
lineBreak = "\r\n";
body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\(lineBreak)");
```

Please try this.